# Script php para saber quantas combinações possíveis é possível ter

Tags: php, algoritmo

Gostaria de criar um script simples, apenas para saber número de possíveis combinações.

Não seria ver a lista de combinações, mas sim somente quantos dígitos poderá ter, podendo ser repedido os números e ou letras.
**Ex**:

```
$Valores = "1, 2"; 
$Digito  = 2; //Quantidade de dígitos.

echo $Resultado = 6; //Possíveis combinações 1,2,12,21,22,11
```

Comment: Tiago, se não me engano se trata de Algoritmo Analise Combinatória. Desculpe se estiver enganado. Você já verificou se [algumas destas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%27Algoritmo+analise+combinat%C3%B3ria%27) te atende?

Comment: @pss1suporte sim, não é a mesma coisa.

Comment: @Maniero, como uma pergunta direta pode se ampla de mais?

Comment: É verdade, nem dá para ser ampla, é fora de escopo conforme [help/on-topic]

Comment: @Maniero, O que esta fora de escopo?

Comment: Isso é matemática, basta você fazer `qnt_valores ^ qnt_digitos` (`pow()` no caso do PHP) para cada quantidade de digito. Talvez exista outra forma...

Comment: Mas as combinações possiveis tem de ter todos os digitos preenchidos ? Pelo seu exemplo parece que não. Se tiverem que ter tudo preenchido é como já foi dito em comentários: `pow(count(explode(',',$Valores)),$Digito)`